# Does the Battlefield 1 campaign have extra/hidden content if I collect all the medals/codexes?

Tags: battlefield-1

I have played the campaign of Battlefield-1 and I loved it. Is there a challenge or hidden maps which is revealed only after I collect all medals, codex?
I can't get enough of this game.

PS: I don't want multiplayer for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collecting codexes and medals are only used for unlocking things in multiplayer.

There are no additional stories to unlock.